# How do I reset my Windows 10 camera to show correct colors again?

Tags: windows-10, camera, integrated-camera

We have a Dell Inspiron 17 3000 computer running Windows 10. The Camera app got used as a mirror occasionally: turn on the camera and look at the screen to see the person in front of the computer. This worked fine for months, got used multiple times a week.

A few days ago it started showing strange colors instead of normal colors. It happens with various light sources. We know of no event that would have changed this; of course there could be one we don't know about. I've compared it to the camera app on an HP Elitebook in the same light, side-by-side; the Elitebook shows normal colors, the Dell shows colors as though everything is violently overexposed, bleached out, you can still make out shapes but nothing looks normal.

I took lens cleaner and a Qtip and cleaned the camera lens. No change.

I went through all the settings for the Camera app on both computers, comparing to see if there was something different that could account for color changes. All settings are the same(now). I've clicked on the button to update the camera driver, I've used the "advanced settings" feature to "reset" the camera, I've rebooted after doing all these things several times. I looked under settings for the video as well as the camera.

Can anyone suggest another place to look? I suppose I can uninstall the camera app, but in fact I'm nervous about finding it to reinstall again. Has anyone else had this happen? Has anyone uninstalled and reinstalled the Windows 10 Camera app?

Comment: @John It has not and not something unexpected. The vast majority of the integrated webcams do not require an user installable drive - they work with generic drivers already included in Windows.

Comment: @John If it's "lacking" it's because it isn't needed, it's as simple as that. And yes, the user may try to uninstall the device, reboot and let it be installed again automatically, it's harmless troubleshooting but I strongly suspect it'll be a waste of time. The symptoms point to wrong settings and/or hardware issue. FYI: Not everything can be solved by trowing software at it, even drivers.